# Какой статус имеет экземпляр внешнего класса по отношению к анонимному?

Tags: java, ооп

Вот на пример:

```
MyClass {
    void m() {
        new Callable<File>() {
            @Override
            public File call() throws Exception {
                 return new SomeClass(И тут нужно послать экземпляр
                                           класса MyClass в котором мы находимся).getFile();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если бы анонимного класса не было, можно было бы послать просто `this`, но с точки зрения анонимного класса что это?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. MyClass.this.getFile()?

Comment: @Александр Мартынцев точно! Вы снова меня спасаете!!! Добавьте ответ я галочку поставлю хоть что то хорошее для вас сделать! Полу чается return new SomeClass(ParallelSearch.this);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для доступа к методам "корневого" класса используйте `MyClass.this`, например:

```
MyClass.this.getFile()
```